# Optimize query that calculates year to date and previous year todate

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following query that calculates year to date and previous year today. How could I optimize it?

;

```
WITH grouped_by_date AS
  (SELECT *
   FROM tmp.FACT_DC s),
     cumulative_sum_for_ytd AS
  (SELECT T.*,
          T1.QTY_UoM_YTD,t1.QTY_YTD,t1.AMOUNT_LCPNV
   FROM grouped_by_date T CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT SUM(QTY_UoM) AS QTY_UoM_YTD,SUM(QTY) AS QTY_YTD, SUM(PNV_LC)as AMOUNT_LCPNV
      FROM grouped_by_date
      WHERE [Delivery_Year]=T.[Delivery_Year]
        AND convert(date,Delivery_Year+'-'+ Delivery_month+'-'+ [Invoicing_Day])<=convert(date,T.Delivery_Year+'-'+ t.Delivery_month+'-'+ t.[Invoicing_Day])
        AND [Sales_Organization]=T.Sales_Organization
        AND[Sales_Product_Name_N3]=T.Sales_Product_Name_N3
        AND[Sales_Product_Name_N2]=T.[Sales_Product_Name_N2]
        AND[Sales_Product_Name_N1]=T.[Sales_Product_Name_N1]
        AND[Market_Segment_Name_N2]=T.[Market_Segment_Name_N2]
        AND[Doc_Currency]=T.Doc_Currency
        AND[User_Name_N1]=T.User_Name_N1
        AND[Engineer_Code]=T.Engineer_Code
        AND[User_Name_N2]=T.User_Name_N2
        AND[Bill_To_Customer_Code]=T.Bill_To_Customer_Code
        AND[User_Country_Code]=T.User_Country_Code
        AND[User_N3_Country_Name]=T.User_N3_Country_Name ) T1)
SELECT lastYear.*,
  (SELECT SUM(thisYear.QTY_UoM) AS QTY_UoM_YTD_prev
   FROM cumulative_sum_for_ytd thisYear
   WHERE convert(int,thisYear.Delivery_Year) = convert(int,lastYear.Delivery_Year - 1)
     AND (convert(int,thisYear.Delivery_Month) < convert(int,lastYear.Delivery_Month)
          OR convert(int,thisYear.Delivery_Month) = convert(int,lastYear.Delivery_Month)
          AND convert(int,thisYear.Invoicing_Day) <- convert(int,lastYear.Invoicing_Day))
     AND thisYear.[Sales_Organization]=lastYear.Sales_Organization
     AND thisYear.[Sales_Product_Name_N3]=lastYear.Sales_Product_Name_N3
     AND thisYear.[Sales_Product_Name_N2]=lastYear.[Sales_Product_Name_N2]
     AND thisYear.[Sales_Product_Name_N1]=lastYear.[Sales_Product_Name_N1]
     AND thisYear.[Market_Segment_Name_N2]=lastYear.[Market_Segment_Name_N2]
     AND thisYear.[Doc_Currency]=lastYear.Doc_Currency
     AND thisYear.[User_Name_N1]=lastYear.User_Name_N1
     AND thisYear.[Engineer_Code]=lastYear.Engineer_Code
     AND thisYear.[User_Name_N2]=lastYear.User_Name_N2
     AND thisYear.[Bill_To_Customer_Code]=lastYear.Bill_To_Customer_Code
     AND thisYear.[User_Country_Code]=lastYear.User_Country_Code
     AND thisYear.[User_N3_Country_Name]=lastYear.User_N3_Country_Name )AS QTY_UoM_YTD_prev,
     (SELECT SUM(thisYear.QTY) 
   FROM cumulative_sum_for_ytd thisYear
   WHERE convert(int,thisYear.Delivery_Year) = convert(int,lastYear.Delivery_Year - 1)
     AND (convert(int,thisYear.Delivery_Month) < convert(int,lastYear.Delivery_Month)
          OR convert(int,thisYear.Delivery_Month) = convert(int,lastYear.Delivery_Month)
          AND convert(int,thisYear.Invoicing_Day) <- convert(int,lastYear.Invoicing_Day))
     AND thisYear.[Sales_Organization]=lastYear.Sales_Organization
```

> ```
>   AND thisYear.[Sales_Product_Name_N3]=lastYear.Sales_Product_Name_N3
>      AND thisYear.[Sales_Product_Name_N2]=lastYear.[Sales_Product_Name_N2]
>      AND thisYear.[Sales_Product_Name_N1]=lastYear.[Sales_Product_Name_N1]
>      AND thisYear.[Market_Segment_Name_N2]=lastYear.[Market_Segment_Name_N2]
>      AND thisYear.[Doc_Currency]=lastYear.Doc_Currency
>      AND thisYear.[User_Name_N1]=lastYear.User_Name_N1
>      AND thisYear.[Engineer_Code]=lastYear.Engineer_Code
>      AND thisYear.[User_Name_N2]=lastYear.User_Name_N2
>      AND thisYear.[Bill_To_Customer_Code]=lastYear.Bill_To_Customer_Code
>      AND thisYear.[User_Country_Code]=lastYear.User_Country_Code
>      AND thisYear.[User_N3_Country_Name]=lastYear.User_N3_Country_Name )AS
> ```
>
> QTY_YTD_prev,
>            (SELECT SUM(thisYear.AMOUNT_LCPNV) 
>          FROM cumulative_sum_for_ytd thisYear
>
> > ```
> > WHERE convert(int,thisYear.Delivery_Year) = convert(int,lastYear.Delivery_Year - 1)
> >      AND (convert(int,thisYear.Delivery_Month) < convert(int,lastYear.Delivery_Month)
> >           OR convert(int,thisYear.Delivery_Month) = convert(int,lastYear.Delivery_Month)
> >           AND convert(int,thisYear.Invoicing_Day) <- convert(int,lastYear.Invoicing_Day))
> >      AND thisYear.[Sales_Organization]=lastYear.Sales_Organization
> >      AND thisYear.[Sales_Product_Name_N3]=lastYear.Sales_Product_Name_N3
> >      AND thisYear.[Sales_Product_Name_N2]=lastYear.[Sales_Product_Name_N2]
> >      AND thisYear.[Sales_Product_Name_N1]=lastYear.[Sales_Product_Name_N1]
> >      AND thisYear.[Market_Segment_Name_N2]=lastYear.[Market_Segment_Name_N2]
> >      AND thisYear.[Doc_Currency]=lastYear.Doc_Currency
> >      AND thisYear.[User_Name_N1]=lastYear.User_Name_N1
> >      AND thisYear.[Engineer_Code]=lastYear.Engineer_Code
> >      AND thisYear.[User_Name_N2]=lastYear.User_Name_N2
> >      AND thisYear.[Bill_To_Customer_Code]=lastYear.Bill_To_Customer_Code
> >      AND thisYear.[User_Country_Code]=lastYear.User_Country_Code
> >      AND thisYear.[User_N3_Country_Name]=lastYear.User_N3_Country_Name )AS
> > ```
> >
> > AMOUNT_LCPNV_prev
> >         FROM cumulative_
>
> sum_for_ytd la

stYear

Comment: You optimize it by switching away from soon-to-be-deprecated software to a more recent version of SQL Server.  Then you can use cumulative sum functionality built-in to the database.

Comment: The `convert` calls aren't known for boosting performance, but you haven't provided any schemas ... .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using CTEs, you could reorganize your code by using temp tables. Putting the right indexes on the Temps will also speed up.

Eg:

```
    drop table if exists #cumulative_sum_for_ytd;

    SELECT T.*,
       T1.QTY_UoM_YTD,t1.QTY_YTD,t1.AMOUNT_LCPNV
INTO #cumulative_sum_for_ytd
FROM tmp.FACT_DC  T
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT SUM(QTY_UoM) AS QTY_UoM_YTD,SUM(QTY) AS QTY_YTD, SUM(PNV_LC)as AMOUNT_LCPNV
    FROM tmp.FACT_DC 
    WHERE [Delivery_Year]=T.[Delivery_Year]
        AND convert(date,Delivery_Year+'-'+ Delivery_month+'-'+ [Invoicing_Day])<=convert(date,T.Delivery_Year+'-'+ t.Delivery_month+'-'+ t.[Invoicing_Day])
        AND [Sales_Organization]=T.Sales_Organization
        AND[Sales_Product_Name_N3]=T.Sales_Product_Name_N3
        AND[Sales_Product_Name_N2]=T.[Sales_Product_Name_N2]
        AND[Sales_Product_Name_N1]=T.[Sales_Product_Name_N1]
        AND[Market_Segment_Name_N2]=T.[Market_Segment_Name_N2]
        AND[Doc_Currency]=T.Doc_Currency
        AND[User_Name_N1]=T.User_Name_N1
        AND[Engineer_Code]=T.Engineer_Code
        AND[User_Name_N2]=T.User_Name_N2
        AND[Bill_To_Customer_Code]=T.Bill_To_Customer_Code
        AND[User_Country_Code]=T.User_Country_Code
        AND[User_N3_Country_Name]=T.User_N3_Country_Name
) T1
```

etc ...